# How to merge 2 arrays in php?

Tags: php

Sorry for the elementary question, but i don't know how make it.
I have 2 arrays in PHP with dummy data

```
 Arr1[
   [0] => [
        [user_id] => 1,
        [first_name] => 'justin',
        [last_name] => 'bieber'
   ],

   [1] => [
        [user_id] => 2,
        [first_name] => 'terry',
        [last_name] => 'crews'
   ]
];

Arr2[
   [0] => [
        [user_id] => 1,
        [height] => 180,
        [weight] => 80
   ],

   [1] => [
        [user_id] => 2,
        [height] => 150,
        [weight] => 70
   ]
];
```

How to merge this arrays and get the result array?

```
ArrResult[
   [0] => [
        [user_id] => 1,
        [first_name] => 'justin',
        [last_name] => 'bieber'
        [height] => 180,
        [weight] => 80
   ],

   [1] => [
        [user_id] => 2,
        [first_name] => 'terry',
        [last_name] => 'crews'
        [height] => 150,
        [weight] => 70
   ]
];
```

Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Better than what?

Comment: Any way to solve

Comment: @symcbean better than notepad

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

Try `array_merge()`:

```
$merged = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $merged[] = array_merge($arr1[$key], $arr2[$key]);
}
```